4x4Go vs 2x8Go RAM modules kits
I want to extend (16Go -> 32Go) the RAM of my PC:

motherboard ASUS X99-A II
CPU Intel Core i7 5820K
RAM CORDAIR VENGEANCE LPX 16GB (4x4GB) DDR4 DRAM 3000MHz C15 Black

The original 4x4 kit is not available anymore.
The closest are:

the 4x4 2666MHz C16 variant,
the 2x8 3000MHz C15 (same specifications).

Concerning the 4x4 kit: the current performances are fine for my usage (and I've even forgotten to enable XMP so they never ran at maximal performance but 2133MHz) so 2666MHz is OK, just worrying if the different CAS latencies could cause any issue.
As for the 2x8 kit, I would not benefit from quad channel, but only dual channel, so I fear that performance could drop a little, and that mixing module sizes could also cause other issues.
What is the best option?

Thanks for your comment; so I'd better go with the 4x4 kit?

OK thanks, and whatever the option there is no risk of performance drop and/or compatibility issues?

OK thanks again, so I'll go with the 4x4 kit. Please add an answer so that I can accept it. :)
